# nullPointerException on AsyncTask doInBackground response

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, retrofit

Hello I keep on getting a NullPointerException on `item.setProduct(trans.getProduct().getName());`
Can you tell why and how? I don't see any reason why would it be null since I've set my adapter in the onPostExecute method. Thanks!

```
private class TransactionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        BackendService service = BackendAPI.serviceApi();
        TransactionObject transactionList;

        Log.e("AsyncTask", "I'm called");

        try {
            transactionList = service.listTransactions(15);
            if (transactionList != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, transactionList.toString());
                loadListViewData(transactionList);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void loadListViewData(TransactionObject transObj) {

        item = new SalesItem();

        Iterator<Transaction> transactionList = transObj.getTransactions().iterator();
        Transaction trans = null;

        while (transactionList.hasNext()) {
            trans = transactionList.next();

            item.setProduct(trans.getProduct().getName());
            item.setCost(trans.getCost());
            item.setName(trans.getUser().getName());
            item.setDate(trans.getCreated_at());
            item.setId(trans.getId());
            transaction.add(item);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        adapter = new SalesListAdapter(getActivity(), transaction);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

here's my log

```
`03-03 07:40:52.604    2011-2033/net.payswitch.switchmobile W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 07:40:52.604    2011-2033/net.payswitch.switchmobile W/System.err﹕ at net.payswitch.switchmobile.fragments.SalesDataFragment$TransactionTask.loadListViewData(SalesDataFragment.java:188)
03-03 07:40:52.604    2011-2033/net.payswitch.switchmobile W/System.err﹕ at net.payswitch.switchmobile.fragments.SalesDataFragment$TransactionTask.doInBackground(SalesDataFragment.java:166)
03-03 07:40:52.604    2011-2033/net.payswitch.switchmobile W/System.err﹕ at net.payswitch.switchmobile.fragments.SalesDataFragment$TransactionTask.doInBackground(SalesDataFragment.java:152)
03-03 07:40:52.604    2011-2033/net.payswitch.switchmobile W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-03 07:40:52.604    2011-2033/net.payswitch.switchmobile W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-03 07:40:52.604    2011-2033/net.payswitch.switchmobile W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-03 07:40:52.604    2011-2033/net.payswitch.switchmobile W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-03 07:40:52.604    2011-2033/net.payswitch.switchmobile W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-03 07:40:52.604    2011-2033/net.payswitch.switchmobile W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)`
```

Comment: You don't have `Product` in your `trans` most probably. Did you check your `trans` object ?

Comment: Maybe `trans.getProduct();` or `trans.getProduct().getName()` is null

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hello Jens and Bharath, I can log the details of `getProduct().getName()` but I can't seem to put it on the `item` object

Comment: In `loadListViewData()` what is the `transaction` object? where is it initialised? same question for `item`.

Answer (score 0):

here's a follow up: (the SalesItem class is on a different file)

```
public class SalesItem {

private String product;
private String cost;
private String name;
private String date;
private String id;

public String getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(String product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public String getCost() {
    return cost;
}

public void setCost(String cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

the declaration below is located inside the parent class, so they are declared globally

```
private ArrayList<SalesItem> transaction;
private SalesItem item;
```

Comment: And you have a `transaction = new ArrayList<>();` that initialise it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with `item`. You create one `new SalesItem()` and then you loop over the transaction list. It means that after the first `SalesItem` added to `transaction`, you will *modify* the `SalesItem` already in `transaction`, and add it *again*. Surely, this is not the intended behaviour.
The solution is to move `new SalesItem()` inside the `while` loop.

For the `NullPointerException`, add a check for each step where you can have `null` and log an explicit error, if you want to proceed for next element in list, or do an `assert` or log with `Log.wtf(...)` if it should not happen:

```
public static final String MY_ACTIVITY = "MyActivity";

public void loadListViewData(TransactionObject transObj) {

        //item = new SalesItem(); moved inside loop

        Iterator<Transaction> transactionList = transObj.getTransactions().iterator();
        Transaction trans = null;

        while (transactionList.hasNext()) {
            trans = transactionList.next();
            if (tran==null) {
               Log.e(MY_ACTIVITY, "trans is null");
               continue;
            }
            if (tran.getProduct()==null) {
               Log.e(MY_ACTIVITY, "Product is null for transId: "+trans.getId());
               continue;
            }
            if (tran.getUser()==null) {
               Log.e(MY_ACTIVITY, "User is null for transId: "+trans.getId();
               continue;
            }
            item = new SalesItem();

            item.setProduct(trans.getProduct().getName());
            item.setCost(trans.getCost());
            item.setName(trans.getUser().getName());
            item.setDate(trans.getCreated_at());
            item.setId(trans.getId());
            transaction.add(item);
        }

    }
```